# The dispersion relationship and density of state of the 2D simple triangular lattice

Tags: homework-and-exercises, solid-state-physics

Calculate the dispersion relationship and density of  state of the 2D simple triangular lattice.  Suppose the atomic mass is m, the distance between adjacent lattice points is a, and the atoms of adjacent lattice points are connected by a spring with elastic coefficient f. Numerically calculate the density of states.

The picture below is my solution, but I am having trouble finding the density of states.
[image]

The mathematica code is as follow:

```
w = Sqrt[(2 f)/m*(3 - Cos[kx a] - 2*Cos[(kx a)/2]*Cos[(Sqrt[3]*ky*a)/2])]
A = Sqrt[(D[w, kx])^2 + (D[w, ky])^2]
```

Comment: It's quite clear from your hand written notes, but you should specify that you mean dispersion relation and D.O.S. of **phonons**

Comment: Also, a rough, but still good, estimate of the D.O.S. can be obtained as follows: randomly generate points in the first Brillouin zone, then apply the dispersion relation $\omega(k_x, k_y)$ to all these points, and use Histogram[] on the resulting list. The largest the number of points you pick, the more precise will be the DOS. 
This is not the smartest way, because you could in principle exploit symmetries of the Brillouin zones to write down quicker code, but it's a starting point! Let me know